# filterDate does not work GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to create LAI (Leaf Area Index) ImageCollection from Sentinel-2 https://code.earthengine.google.com/558a6788e0c9db0c645ac6cd49debe51.

My process is like this: S2_collection -> output_collection_LAI (using SL2P library) -> LAI_collection_withTime (adding 'time_start' from S2_collection, this step for creating LAI profile in the future).

But I realised that when I used the filterDate function for the LAI_collection_withTime, it seemed not work.

For example, when I tested the size of S2_collection from '2019-01-01' to '2019-01-31', it was 48. But when I filtered the LAI_collection_withTime from '2019-01-01' to '2019-01-16', it was still 48, while it should be 24.

The code is below:

```
var dictionariesSL2P = require('users/richardfernandes/SL2P:dictionaries-SL2P'); // Specify collection and algorithms
var S2 = require('users/richardfernandes/SL2P:toolsS2')                     // Cloud masking and geometry for S2
var ib = require('users/richardfernandes/SL2P:imageBands')                     // Cloud masking and geometry
var SL2P = require('users/richardfernandes/SL2P:SL2P')                     // Cloud masking and geometry

var collectionName_harmonized = "COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED";

// Fetch collection options and filtered S2 composite
var colOptions = ee.Dictionary(ee.Dictionary(dictionariesSL2P.make_collection_options()).get(collectionName_harmonized));
var S2_collection = ee.ImageCollection(collectionName_harmonized)
            .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31')
            .filterBounds(geometry);
//print(S2_collection.size());

switch (collectionName_harmonized) {
  case "COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED":
    S2_collection = S2_collection.map(S2.S2MaskClear)
                                 .map(S2.addS2Geometry.bind(null,colOptions))
  break;
}

var var_LAI = 'LAI'
var output_collection_LAI = ee.ImageCollection(SL2P.applySL2P(collectionName_harmonized, S2_collection, var_LAI, dictionariesSL2P));

//print(output_collection_LAI.size());

var matchedTimeStart = function(image){
  var timeStart = S2_collection.filter(ee.Filter.equals('system: index', image.get('system: index')))
                               .first()
                               .get('system:time_start');
  return image.set('system:time_start', timeStart);
};
var LAI_collection_withTime = output_collection_LAI.map(matchedTimeStart);
//print(LAI_collection_withTime.size());

var filteredCollection = ee.ImageCollection(LAI_collection_withTime).filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-16');
print(filteredCollection.size());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because you have a misplaced space in your `system:index` property keys inside the `matchedTimeStart` function.

```js
var matchedTimeStart = function(image){
  //                                     remove the space here |      and the space here |
  //                                                           V                         V
  var timeStart = S2_collection.filter(ee.Filter.equals('system:index', image.get('system:index')))
                               .first()
                               .get('system:time_start');
  return image.set('system:time_start', timeStart);
};
```